# RPM to DPKG: Underscore in Package Name

Tags: rpm, package-management, saltstack, dpkg

I have a custom RPM which I convert to DPKG using the tool `alien`.

It works with one annoyance:

The input is called "foo_bar.rpm" and the output is called "foo-bar.dpkg".

We have a list of packages to install via automated configuration management (salt-stack).

If I try to install "foo_bar" on Debian it fails, if I try to install "foo-bar" on RedHat/Suse it fails ...

I would like to avoid to manage two lists of package names...

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on github which tries to bring sanity into this package naming chaos:

https://github.com/unixpackage/unixpackage

> One command to install equivalent packages in Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, Fedora, Red Hat and Mac OS X.
>   UnixPackage is a UNIX independent way of installing packages. Specify the Ubuntu package name (e.g. libpq-dev), and it will install the equivalent on your system (e.g. postgresql-libs on Arch).